# How to access all rows and columns in Tableu python script?

Tags: tableau-api

With TabPy I can add some dynamic columns like

```
SCRIPT_STR('return _arg1', ATTR([SomeColumn]))
```

My Requirement:

1. Process all rows in a table and compute a constant value say x1
2. Add a dynamic column for all rows like x1 + valueOf(SomeColumn)

Not sure how to achieve this. Is it possible in Tableau ?

**PS:** The steps 1 & 2 should be recomputed on changing filter

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried unticking the 'Aggregate Measures' from the Analysis Menu?
It should process all rows and columns separately. Now it must be taking everything in aggregation.

Let me know if you are finding any errors or such.